# HDLCompiler:1731 - WASHING MACHINE CONTROLLER VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

I am trying to write VHDL language for a washing machine controller, but cannot understand the reason why I am having the errors when I synthesis below:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - Line 152: found '0' definitions of operator "/", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "/"

ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - Line 156: found '0' definitions of operator " * ", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for " * "

ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - Line 160: found '0' definitions of operator " * ", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for " * "

ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - Line 164: found '0' definitions of operator " * ", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for " * "

ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - Line 168: found '0' definitions of operator " * ", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for " * "

ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - Line 172: found '0' definitions of operator " * ", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for " * "

ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - Line 176: found '0' definitions of operator " * ", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for " * "

ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - Line 180: found '0' definitions of operator " * ", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for " * "
```

The machine starts when a laundry token is deposited. It then sequences through the following stages: Soak - Wash - Rinse - Spin 
There is a “double wash” switch, which, if turned on, causes a second wash and rinse to occur. In other 
words, the “double wash” switch causes the following 6-stage sequence:

Soak - Wash - Rinse - Wash - Rinse - Spin

The error in question relates to the code below:

```
process(reset,clk_in)
begin
    if reset='1' then
        current_state<=s0;
        i:=0;
        elsif clk_in'event and clk_in='1' then
            if i < state_time and current_state/=s7 then
                i := i + 1;
        end if;

        if current_state=s0 then
            sevenseg_timer<="1000000";
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and i >=0 and i <= state_time/9 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0010000"; --9
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and state_time/9 and i <= (state_time/9)*2 then
            sevenseg_timer<="0000000"; --8
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 2 and i <= (state_time/9)*3 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "1111000"; --7
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 3 and i <= (state_time/9)*4 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0000010"; --6
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 4 and i <= (state_time/9)*5 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0010010"; --5
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 5 and i <= (state_time/9)*6 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0011001"; --4
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 6 and i <= (state_time/9)*7 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0110000"; --3
        end if;

        if current_state=s0 and (state_time/9)* 7 and i <= (state_time/9)*8 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0100100"; --2
        end if;

        if current_state=s0 and (state_time/9) * 8 and i <= (state_time/9)*9 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "1111001"; --1
        end if;

        if current_state = s6 and lid='1' then
            current_state <=s7;
        end if;

        if current_state = s7 and Lid='0' then
            current_state <= s6;
        end if;

        if i =state_time then
            i :=0;
            current_state<=next_state;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

all the code can be seen below.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity VMC_VDL is
Port ( clk_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
       DW : in  STD_LOGIC;
       T : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Soak : out  STD_LOGIC;
       Wash : out  STD_LOGIC;
       Rinse : out  STD_LOGIC;
       Spin : out  STD_LOGIC;
       Lid : in  STD_LOGIC;
       sevenseg_statenumber : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
       sevenseg_timer : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0):="1000000");


end VMC_VDL;

architecture Behavioral of VMC_VDL is
    type state_type is (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7);
    signal current_state, next_state:state_type;
    shared variable i : integer range 0 to 50000;
    shared variable state_time : integer range 0 to 50000;
    shared variable base_time: integer := 25;

begin

process(current_state, T)
begin
case current_state is
    when s0 =>
        Soak <='0';
        Wash <= '0';
        Rinse <= '0';
        Spin <= '0';
        sevenseg_statenumber<="1111001"; --1
        state_time:=1;
        if T='1' then
            next_state<=s1;
            else next_state<=s0;
        end if;
    when s1 =>
        Soak <='1';
        Wash <= '0';
        Rinse <= '0';
        Spin <= '0';
        sevenseg_statenumber<="1111001"; --1
        state_time:=base_time*5;
        if DW='1' then
            next_state<=s2;
            else next_state<=s4;
        end if;
    when s2 =>
        Soak <='0';
        Wash <= '1';
        Rinse <= '0';
        Spin <= '0';
        sevenseg_statenumber<="0100100"; --2
        state_time:=base_time*3;
        next_state <=s3;
    when s3 =>
        Soak <='0';
        Wash <= '0';
        Rinse <= '1';
        Spin <= '0';
        sevenseg_statenumber<="0110000"; --3
        state_time:=base_time*4;
        next_state <=s4;
    when s4 =>
        Soak <='0';
        Wash <= '1';
        Rinse <= '0';
        Spin <= '0';
        sevenseg_statenumber<="0011001"; --4
        state_time:=base_time*3;
        next_state <=s5;
    when s5 =>
        Soak <='0';
        Wash <= '0';
        Rinse <= '1';
        Spin <= '0';
        sevenseg_statenumber<="0010010"; --5
        state_time:=base_time*4;
        next_state <=s6;
    when s6 =>
        Soak <='0';
        Wash <= '0';
        Rinse <= '0';
        Spin <= '1';
        sevenseg_statenumber<="0000010"; --6
        state_time:=base_time*10;
        next_state <=s0;
    when s7 =>
        Soak <='0';
        Wash <= '0';
        Rinse <= '0';
        Spin <= '0';
        sevenseg_statenumber<="1000011"; --L
        state_time:=base_time*10;
    end case;
end process;

process(reset,clk_in)
begin
    if reset='1' then
        current_state<=s0;
        i:=0;
        elsif clk_in'event and clk_in='1' then
            if i < state_time and current_state/=s7 then
                i := i + 1;
        end if;

        if current_state=s0 then
            sevenseg_timer<="1000000";
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and i >=0 and i <= state_time/9 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0010000"; --9
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and state_time/9 and i <= (state_time/9)*2 then
            sevenseg_timer<="0000000"; --8
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 2 and i <= (state_time/9)*3 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "1111000"; --7
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 3 and i <= (state_time/9)*4 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0000010"; --6
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 4 and i <= (state_time/9)*5 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0010010"; --5
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 5 and i <= (state_time/9)*6 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0011001"; --4
        end if;

        if current_state/=s0 and (state_time/9) * 6 and i <= (state_time/9)*7 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0110000"; --3
        end if;

        if current_state=s0 and (state_time/9)* 7 and i <= (state_time/9)*8 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "0100100"; --2
        end if;

        if current_state=s0 and (state_time/9) * 8 and i <= (state_time/9)*9 then
            sevenseg_timer<= "1111001"; --1
        end if;

        if current_state = s6 and lid='1' then
            current_state <=s7;
        end if;

        if current_state = s7 and Lid='0' then
            current_state <= s6;
        end if;

        if i =state_time then
            i :=0;
            current_state<=next_state;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;




end Behavioral;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted your error messages as code so that they take up less space in the question. And, at least for me, the unicode characters in the question (adter Soak etc.) do not render correctly. Are they important for the question?

Comment: thank you! no they arent important just to space the states out. thanks.

Comment: In that case you can remove them using the edit function (right below the tags under your question).

Comment: Don't use shared variables. In fact, preferably don't use variables at all. This is VHDL, not a microcontroller programming language. Use signals (representing wires).

Comment: but the errors relate to the ' * ' and ' / ' , would doing so prevent  it from causing errors?

Comment: Declarations can be made directly visible through use clauses.  You have no use clause making overload operator function declarations for "/", "*" visible using signature matching (operands and result types). Your ISE HDLCompiler isn't gracefully handling shared variable declarations, the errors devolve from there. Don't use shared variables. Division and multiplication would only be supported in synthesis for powers of two at best or in static (constant) expressions.  See the XST (Xilinx Synthesis Technology) User Guide matching your ISE version.

Comment: thank you for you're answers much appreciated. i managed to code it in an alternative method and it is now working perfectly. thank you again.